# List view itemclick event appcelerator

Tags: listview, appcelerator

I have a JSON defined in the code with and image, a title, a date and  a url. This will be used to populate the list view. On the click event of any list item, I need to navigate to a different controller and render the view in it having the videoplayer that plays the video according to the clicked list item's url and i want to display the date and title too.
I am not understanding how to code this in the itemClick event. Please help!

This is my .js file for DashboardController.

```
Alloy.createController('VideoPlayerController',videoInfo[i]).getView();
var sections = [];
//JSON to populate the listview
var videoInfo = [{
    pic : "/Images/playButton.png",
    info : "This in the the title for the first video.",
    date : "03/07/2017",
    url : "https://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9khttps://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9k"
}, {
    pic : "/Images/playButton.png",
    info : "This in the the title for the second video.",
    date : "03/07/2017",
    url : "https://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9khttps://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9k"
}, {
    pic : "/Images/playButton.png",
    info : "This in the the title for the third video.",
    date : "03/07/2017",
    url : "https://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9khttps://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9k"
}];

function populateListView() {
    Ti.API.trace("[DashboardController.js  >>  populateListView() >>]");
    if (!_.isEmpty(videoInfo)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < videoInfo.length; i++) {
            var item = {
                template : "videoTemplate",
                iconId : {
                    image : videoInfo[i].pic
                },
                titleId : {
                    text : videoInfo[i].info
                },
                dateId : {
                    text : videoInfo[i].date
                },
                urlId : {
                    text : videoInfo[i].url
                },
                properties : {
                    backgroundColor : "transparent"
                }
            };
            sections.push(item);
        }
       $.listSection.setItems(sections);
    }
}  
populateListView();
$.lView.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var dataItem = $.listSection.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);    
});
```

And the .xml file for DashboardController isthis :

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="win2" class="container">
        <View id = "v1" class ="view1"  layout ="horizontal" >
            <Button class="btnBack" ></Button>
            <Label  class = "label1">LIST VIEW EXAMPLE</Label>
        </View>
        <View class="view2">
            <TextField id = "txtSearch"></TextField>
        </View>
        <ListView id = "lView" class = "list1" >
             <Templates>
                    <ItemTemplate name="videoTemplate">
                        <View class = "viewTemplate" layout = "horizontal" >
                            <ImageView bindId="iconId"  id="pic"  />
                            <View class = "viewTitle" layout = "vertical" >
                                <Label bindId="titleId" id="info" />
                                <View class="viewDtUrl" layout="horizontal" >
                                    <Label bindId="dateId" id="date" />
                                    <Label bindId="urlId" id ="url" /> 
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </ItemTemplate> 
            </Templates>
            <ListSection id = "listSection">
            </ListSection>
        </ListView>   
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

This is the .xml file of the controller that will be rendering the video player (VideoPlayerController) is this:

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
        <VideoPlayer class = "video"></VideoPlayer>
        <View class="videoView">
            <Label class="titleInfo"></Label>
            <View class = "infoLabel">
                <Label class="dateInfo"></Label>
                <Label class="urlInfo"></Label>
            </View>>
        </View>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  Here are a couple of items:

1. Move the first line in DashboarController.js, `Alloy.createController('VideoPlayerController',videoInfo[i]).getView();` down into the `lView` event listener.
2. The listview event we want to listen for is called [`itemclick`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView-event-itemclick), not `click`, so change that.
3. The `videoInfo` array is serving as our data collection.  The `itemclick` callback will be returned the index of the row clicked, and this will match the order of our `videoInfo` array, so we can just pass it to `createController` as: `videoInfo[e.itemIndex]`
4. Lastly, `createController` is returning a view with `.getView()`, in our case, this probably a `TiUIWindow` object, so we need to open that window with `.open()`.

This gives us:

```
$.lView.addEventListener('itemclick', function (e) {
    Alloy.createController('VideoPlayerController', videoInfo[e.itemIndex]).getView().open();
});
```

Now in our `VideoPlayerController.js`, we'll have something like:

```
var args = $.args;
console.log('video url:' + args.url);
```

From there, you can use the data passed to `args` to set up the rest of your window.

Comment: Thanks Adam! :) You just saved my day! :) and yes this works absolutely fine. Cheers!